# proving Stokes' theorem with the curl

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, stokes-theorem, curl

How does a curl explain why the Stokes' Theorem is true? From my understanding, the curl is a circulation of vectors and can be viewed as an infinitesimal circulation to explain it, but I'm confused on the relation.

Comment: The curl is a certain summary of derivatives of a vector field ${\bf F}$, encoded in a single vector ${\rm curl}({\bf F})$. It can never explain why Stokes' theorem is true.

Answer (score 0):

Stokes' theorem states that 
$$\int F\cdot dr=\iint \operatorname{curl}(F).n \,ds$$

For example, think of a fluid in a $3$ dimensional space, it can swirl in any direction, then $\operatorname{curl}(F)$ is a vector point that denotes the direction of axis of rotation of the moving fluid. Note that with any closed curve $C$, along with any surface $S$ with boundary $C$, the line integral of $F$ around $C$ is equal to the sum of the "curls" of $F$ on the surface $S$.